# Ajax error with URL (PHP zend framework)

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I have problem in Ajax request.
I am working on PHP5 with Zend framework, locally on wamp server.
On one local site called http://internship/conv I try to do Ajax request to action from my controller (ConvController).
Everytime i get some error (500 or 404).
Something wrong is with url but i try everything. Have you some idea?

Here is the Code of View Index.phtml

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/ConvController/index',
            type:       'POST',
            dataType:   'json',
            cache:      false,
            async:      true,
            data:       $("#RubVal").serialize(),
            success: function(data, status){
                msg = data['plnValue'].valueOf();
                $('#resultConversion').html(msg);
            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (xhr.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connected.\nVerify Network.');
                } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
                    alert('Server Error [500].');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Remote sever unavailable.\nPlease try later');
                }
            }
        });
```

In Zend Framework i crated module "Conv" and controller "ConvController" in ConvController I have indexAction.

ConvController -> indexAction code

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // ajax is calling

        $inputValue = $request->getPost()->rubValue;
        $currencyValue = str_replace(',', '.', $inputValue);

        $this->logVisit($inputValue);

        // input validation
        $errorArray = array();
        if ( ! $this->validCurrencyInput( $currencyValue)) {
            $mtmt =  'Unclear: '. $inputValue . '...?' . $currencyValue;
            $errorArray = array(
                'plnValue' => 'Unclear: '. $inputValue . '...?',
                'success'=>false,
            );

        }

        // exchange conversion
        $plnValue = $this->convertCurrency("RUB", "PLN", $currencyValue);
        if ($plnValue == -1) {
            $errorArray = array(
                'plnValue' => 'Data unavailable',
                'success'=>false,
            );
        }

        // building view for json
        if (empty( $errorArray)) {
            $view = new JsonModel(array(
                'plnValue' => $currencyValue . ' RUB = ' . $plnValue . ' PLN',
                'success'=>true,
            ));
        } else {
            $view = new JsonModel( $errorArray);
        }
        $view->setTerminal(true);

    } else {
        // regular HTTP call
        $view = new ViewModel;
    }

    return $view;
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `500 - internal server error` means your ajax call does not reach the action method most probably due to incorrect url/method name or you did not provide valid inputs to the method. `404` is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Your url is wrong url: '/ConvController/index',. Change it to `"MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION"` and it should work, unless you have any other errors.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong about `500 - internal server error` @Rohit416. `500 - internal server error` means you have some error in your code on specified URL. `404 - Not Found` means you are accessing invalid URL.

Comment: Yep true, may be my words did not justice what i tried to say but my intention was similar, **500: when the method url is correct but the input given was not valid for the method**, which means error hanging on top of the method.